# Creating Font with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins

I know this is a really general question, but don't worry, I'll accept any answer so it doesn't bother anybody.

I'm trying to create a 'Font creator' inside my page, I'm basicly looking for a plugin or framework to do it since I don't want it to take too much of my time because it's a big app, does anybody have any idea of how and with what I could acomplish something like this?

I've done a ton of research & haven't found a good example to work with, any help woul'd be greatly appreciated.

As an extra, this app will be packaged with Electron, wich means I can use some node.js dependency of some sort if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can have node.js running, I think you can run `node_modules` along with it, Try to use [grunt-webfont](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont). This is what I used for [Font WSO2](http://wso2-dev-ux.github.io/font-wso2/) project.